# Alternative to WorkflowServiceHost for WF4?

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation-4

We're looking to replace a chunk of our business logic with WF4 workflows.
They're all pretty typical workflows: User action creates an instance, database effort, next user confirms, etc.

Our requirements for the workflow host are:

1. Create workflows from XAML definitions stored in a database (DynamicActivity)
2. Support workflows on different versions
3. Support long time-based events (we're currently aware of notifications after 5 days and rolling back a workflow after 30 days)
4. Support many instances of many workflows (we've identified 10 workflows with about 4000 in-flight, of which only a few are processing at any one time)
5. Retain all state after a service restart (including the time-based event)
6. Authenticate the calling user (WindowsAuthentication, if possible)

As part of the migration effort, I built some POCs using "WCF Workflow Service Application" projects, but from what I can see these aren't immediately possible.

I've got that #2 is done through WCF Routing, and my understanding is that WSH will handle #3 for us (is this true, given #5?), but I can't see how #1 would work from the default project structure.
I've solved #1 using WorkflowApplication instances, but this relied on using bookmarks to resume for each input event, and I wasn't convinced that WorkflowApplication would scale to our needs without unloading idle workflows, which breaks the Delay activity.

So, if you've stuck with me this far:

- Is there a way to achieve all of this using WSH, either in the default project or by implementing some of it ourselves?
- Are we better off writing our own "DurableDelay" activity that records the true wake time and unloads the workflow to be resumed by the host process, given the long durations and potential need to unload and reload workflows?
- If WSH isn't going to do it, is there an existing alternative?

I'm not averse to writing our own host service to handle workflow lifecycle, and we've even drawn up the proposed design, but I didn't want to start down that route if it turns out that there is a ready-made solution.

Cheers

Comment: Just wanted to follow up that we ended up building our own runtime.  
Effectively, it's a pool of WorkflowApplications that are unloaded after being inactive for 5 seconds. There's a simple scheduler that monitors the expected wake time of existing workflows and loads them in to a WorkflowApplication instance just before they're expected.  
Took a few days, but it's lightweight and does exactly what we need. Plus, we spun it up on 10 boxes in seconds and had automatic loadbalancing (you can't have a single workflow in more than one host).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve **#1** by using a [`VirtualPathProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.virtualpathprovider.aspx) to load your workflows from a database instead of the file system. See [How To Build Workflow Services with a Database Repository](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Workflow-TV/AppFabrictv-How-To-Build-Workflow-Services-with-a-Database-Respository) for more information about this.

Workflow versioning (**#2**) is something that is not supported in .NET 4.0, but in .NET 4.5 you have better support for real versioning. See [What's New in Windows Workflow Foundation 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781025.aspx). However, if you don't need to change a workflow after it starts and just need that new instances start with a new version while already executing instances can finish using a previous workflow definition then you can implement versioning at the database level and just treat each workflow definition version has a different workflow service.

You can then use Workflow Services hosted in IIS ([AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849.aspx)) with a SQL Server instance store to get **#3**, **#4** and **#5** almost for free.

Finally for **#6** and assuming you stick with .NET 4.0 you can take a look at [WF Security Pack CTP 1](http://wf.codeplex.com/releases/view/48114).

Comment: Thanks for that.
For #2 ("each workflow definition version has a different workflow service"), I'll look in to that. We were ideally hoping to have one service per workflow type with versioning done by routing; not sure how this works with AppFabric, so I'll check both options out.
I'll also have to see whether AppFabric is a viable option for us, as installing anything is a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing the same kind of workflows.

I also first gave a look to workflow services, but as our workflow were completely integrated in a business layer, I didn't want to use WCF to access workflows.
So I'm now using WorkflowApplication as host, so I can instantiate and manipulate the host.
Biggest problem was resuming workflows that use a delay activity (you need to check yourself in the database)